# Making lists display side by side using display:inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have two lists that are to be rendered side by side.
First, my right list alone has `display:inline` property.
The lists came out as,
[image]

The goals are not met, since the right side box is rendered below the left side box. So, I made left side box also as `display:inline`. Now, it looks all broken like,
[image]

My css code is

```
#left, #right {
width: 400px;
display: inline;
padding: 12px 45px;
margin-bottom: 6px;
border-top: 2px solid red;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
border-left: thick double #ff0000;
border-right: thick double #ff0000;
```

}

So, how to display two `ul tags` side by side? Why does making display:inline breaks the left box into two pieces?

Comment: sounds like you're looking for `display:flex` or perhaps `column-count:2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<section>
<ul class=left>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>asdf</li>

</ul>
<ul class=right>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>bye</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

with css:

```
section { display: flex; }
section > ul { flex:1 }
```

would do it (https://jsfiddle.net/hus50pzp/1/)

Comment: Although both current answers solve the problem, this one is forward looking, so I like this. Beware of browser compatibility when implementing this solution, as for older ones it *might* requiere vendor prefixes.

Comment: I would suggest always passing your css through autoprefixer (https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) before letting it touch users.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `display:table-cell`

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>ABC</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>ABC</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    display:table;
    width:100%; /*optional*/
    border:1px solid red; /*optional*/
}
div ul {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/661/